# TFS 2015 test case outcome = "None"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 to run automated regression tests nightly. There are over 100 tests in the suite but each night 1 of them, usually the same one, shows up with the outcome "None".

If I look at the test log I see that the test does not fail. If I remove this test from the suite then on the next run the test above that one, in code, will show as "None" but it also passes.

What could cause this and how do I determine the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We upload results after finishing execution of the set of tests given
>   to an agent. From [#1410](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1410) it sounded like all your tests are
>   currently going to 1 machine, which would mean all results are
>   uploaded only at the end. Also, the Test Results tab in Build Summary
>   (image you pasted above) only shows results once the run is complete.
>   You can go to the Runs tab in the Test Hub to see test results as and
>   when they are available, even for in progress runs (image below)
>
> *[Source Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1413)*

[image]

So in other words, you have to wait for the **full completion of the process**, the root cause of the status none issue maybe either your enitre test process haven't finished yet or something special cause the process not finished.

Comment: The "None" result is what shows after the full completion. The specific test that gets this is early in the test cases as well. It is however always the last test in the Run Functional Tests.  I have several Test Steps and all of them after this particular step pass with no problems.

Comment: Not sure why yet but it seems like when this particular test runs TFS does not notice that it is finishing. I have commented out steps in the test to determine which step it is.